# "Add Function Import" Stored procedure missing from list

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Can anyone tell me why only 1 stored procedure only is showing, if I have 5 stored procedures available?

The permissions for the missing one are the same as the one that's showing, but I am still not seeing it in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I need to add the Stored Procedure to the list of Stored Procedures in the Model Browser first to have it appear in the dropdown list.